# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'slice') ------ Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

Tags: javascript

I really appreciate some help with this code. It was working before in google sheets but suddenly started showing up with error messages.

The full code is below :

```
function getDataForSearch() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("TEST FORMULAR");
  return ws.getRange(6, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 6).getValues();
  
}
```

```
function setDataForSearch(){

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(dataReturned){
          data = dataReturned.slice();
        }).getDataForSearch();

      }
```

```
      
      function search(){

        var searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput").value.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
        var searchWords = searchInput.split(/\s+/);
        var searchColumns = [0];

        var resultsArray = searchInput == "" ? [] : data.filter(function(r){

          return searchWords.every(function(word){
            return searchColumns.some(function(colIndex){
              return r[colIndex].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) != -1;
            });
          });
    
        });

        var searchResultsBox =  document.getElementById("searchResults");
        var templateBox = document.getElementById("rowTemplate");
        var template = templateBox.content;

        searchResultsBox.innerHTML = "";

        resultsArray.forEach(function(r){

          var tr = template.cloneNode(true);
          var typeInitiativeColumn = tr.querySelector(".type-initiative");
          var pepRefColumn = tr.querySelector(".pep-ref");
          var projectNameColumn = tr.querySelector(".project-name");

          pepRefColumn.textContent = r[0];
          typeInitiativeColumn.textContent = r[1];
          projectNameColumn.textContent = r[2];
          searchResultsBox.appendChild(tr);

        });

      }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `data` is either `undefined` or `dataReturned` is returning `null`. You can do a workaround, like

```
var data = []; // define globally

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (dataReturned) {
    if (dataReturned.length) { // check if dataReturned is not null in setDataForSearch function
        data = dataReturned.slice();
    }
}).getDataForSearch();

// then check if data is defined & not empty in search function
var resultsArray = !data.length || searchInput == "" ? [] : data.filter(function (r) {

});
```

**Edit** Replace

```
!data.length || searchInput == "" ?
```

with

```
data === null || searchInput == "" ?
```

Comment: Thank you !! I gonna try it

Comment: Now I got this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')

Comment: Could you help me please ?

Comment: Does it say anywhere if its giving error for `dataReturned` or `data` ?

Comment: No it doesn't get any error for dataReturned

Comment: I have updated my answer, see if that works for you

Comment: Hi !! I got this error now : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')

Comment: function setDataForSearch(){
 
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (dataReturned) {
    if (dataReturned.length) { // check if dataReturned is not null in setDataForSearch function
        data = dataReturned.slice();
    }
}).getDataForSearch();
 
      }

Comment: var resultsArray = data === null || searchInput == "" ? [] : data.filter(function (r) {
          
           return searchWords.every(function(word){
            return searchColumns.some(function(colIndex){
              return r[colIndex].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) !== -1;
            });
          });
 
});

Answer (score 0):

Create an if condition as below

```
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(dataReturned){
      if(dataReturned && typeof dataReturned !== 'undefined'){
          data = dataReturned.slice();
      }else {
          data = "null or undefined" 
                 //or do whatever you want in else
     }
    }).getDataForSearch();
```

It will check if `dataReturned` is not null or undefined. If null/undefined/false, it will not execute whatever provided in the if condition.

**Why the error happened?**
You are trying to get something from a null/undefined. It is something like
`null.slice()` you did

Comment: It looks like dataReturned is undefined I don't understand why. I return data from my function getDataForSearch(). I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(dataReturned){
      data = dataReturned?.slice();
    }).getDataForSearch();
```